# Why I am Getting Error while installing discord.py on windows

Tags: python, pip, discord, discord.py

While i was tying to install discord.py, i got alort of error.

> i used this code while installing `discord.py` : `pip install discord.py` and this is the error i got
> :[Click_here_to_see_errors_i_got](https://pastebin.com/sLZ3ZLKX)

Answer (score 0):

Reading the bottom of your paste, it says that its failing to compile the `yarl` library because you are missing Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0:

> Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with
> "Microsoft C++ Build Tools":
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Based on your pastebin, you are trying to install discord.py on Python 3.9. I don't remember having to download build tools when I installed it which I believe is because the `yarl` dependency [does not provide already built wheels for Python 3.9](https://github.com/aio-libs/yarl/releases/tag/v1.6.0). I installed it without issues on Python 3.8.